# Blow-up and regular sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'd like how to deduce, if it's possible that:

the blowup of an affine variety $X$ along $V(g_1,\ldots,g_k)$ is $V(t_i g_j-t_j g_i)_{i,j}\hookrightarrow X\times\text{Proj}(k[t_1,\ldots,t_k])$ if the sequence $(g_1,\ldots,g_k)$ is regular

from the fact that:

if $(g_1,\ldots,g_k)$ is regular genrating an ideal $I$ then
$$ (A/I)[t_1,\ldots,t_k]\simeq\text{gr}_I A=\oplus I^n/I^{n+1} $$
by evaluation on the $g_i$.

For me blowup along $V(I)$ is $\text{Proj}(\oplus I^n)$. As we have $A[t_i]\to \oplus I^n$ surjective by evaluation on the $g_i$ so we have $\text{Proj}(\oplus I^n)\hookrightarrow X\times \mathbb{P}^{k-1}$ closed immersion of equations $\ker(A[t_i]\to\oplus I^n)$ which, by the result, is $I[t_i]$. Here I have problem because I don't see why $I[t_i]$ should be generated by the $g_jt_i-g_it_j$.

Comment: This is Theorem 1.3 in "On the Symmetric and Rees Algebras of an Ideal" by Valla in Manuscripta Math. (30) 1980 though I'm not familiar with the proof.

Comment: @Youngsu Unfortunatly I don't have any free access to this article...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Why do you want to prove it from the isomorphism? I believe you are essentially using the fact that $g_i$ form a regular sequence. The book of Swanson and Huneke may contain a proof you want (I am positive that they contain the statement).

Comment: @Youngsu I want to prove it from the isomorphism because I was thinking that they are closely related. But if there is a direct proof I take it! I'm going to see if I can find this book

Answer (score 1):

The book of Swanson and Huneke is indeed very good for studying defining equations of Rees algebras. It is in section 5.5 page 110.

The central idea is that for some ideals $I=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ called of **linear type** if the defining equations are only given by the relations (the syzygies) between the generator $x_i$ (if $\sum_i a_i x_i$ is a relation then $\sum_i a_i t_i$ is clearly a (linear) equation of the Rees algebra).

It can be proven ideal generated by regular sequence are of linear type. But for regular sequence the Koszul complex is exact so that the relations between the $x_i$ are only the Koszul relations $x_i x_j- x_j x_i=0$ so that the equations of the Rees algebra are the $x_iT_j-x_j T_i=0$.

The key point if so to prove that ideal generated by regular sequence are of linear type. It is more generaly the case if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is a **d-sequence**:
$$ (x_0,\ldots,x_i):x_{i+1}x_j=(x_0,\ldots,x_i):x_j $$
for all $0\leqslant i\leqslant n-1$ and for all $j\geqslant i+1$
It is not difficult to see that regular sequence are d-sequences because $x_{i+1}$ is a regular element in $A/(x_1,\ldots,x_i)$

The fact that d-sequences are of linear type is a direct corolary of Theorem 5.5.4 page 111 in Swanson and Huneke with an half page for proof.

I don't know I there is some more direct proof for the specific case a regular sequence.